# I can't figure how to use correctly "try" in JAVA

Tags: java, try-catch, calculator

I have to treat error "InputMismatchException" on a "application" which calculates numbers depending on which operator user inputs.
I use there in my cod the "try" but after that my operations "gather, reduction, division, multiplication" doesn't work anymore.
Where should i use this "try" in my code if the user inputs a number for example when he have to input an operator and to treat error, not failing my build and keep asking the user what he want to do.

```
package t3;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class T3 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String answer;
    do{

    Scanner ab = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input what operation do you want to do!");
    System.out.println("For gather: \"+\"");
    System.out.println("For reduction: \"-\"");
    System.out.println("For division: \"/\"");
    System.out.println("For multiplication: \"*\"");
    System.out.print(":");

    String operation = ab.nextLine();


    try{
    System.out.print("Input first number: ");
    int nr1 = ab.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input second number: ");
    int nr2 = ab.nextInt();

    int gather, reduction, division, multiplication;
    gather=nr1+nr2;
    reduction=nr1-nr2;
    division=nr1/nr2;
    multiplication=nr1*nr2;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
    { System.out.println(" ------------------------------ You have to choose an operation ------------------------------"); }
    switch (operation){
        case "+" : System.out.println("The result is: " +gather);
        break;
        case "-" : System.out.println("The result is: " +reduction);
        break;
        case "/" : System.out.println("The result is: " +division);
        break;
        case "*" : System.out.println("The result is: " +multiplication);
        break;
        default : System.out.println(" !!!! You haven't chosen an operation...  \n **** Input smth like: \n+ -> gather\n- -> reduction\n/ -> division\n* -> multiplication");  
    } 

                System.out.println("Do you keep going? Yes/ No");
                Scanner tx = new Scanner(System.in);
                answer= tx.nextLine();
    }

    while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
}
}
```

EDIT: After i use there the "try", it gives me this error if i put the normal inputs:
    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
    at tema2.Tema2.main(Tema2.java:104)
C:\Users\VALENTIN-CLAUDIUCOST\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\VALENTIN-CLAUDIUCOST\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)`

Comment: what is your actual error?

Comment: I've googled for you [try-catch-in-java](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/)

Comment: @B001ᛦ, i will take a look after your link, i searched diffs methods but i can t figured out.

Comment: Never try to run code that doesn't compile! Please show the error that your compiler gives you, not the JVM's error. The compiler message will often be more informative

Comment: You have to think of the catch block of a try-catch that it could always be executed without any line inside the try successfully executing. So the problem is that you declare your int variables as local variables inside the try block so are unknown inside your catch block. You could move the declaration of those variables before the try block, but then you would have to consider that inside the catch block they might not have been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class T3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer;
        do {

            Scanner ab = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input what operation do you want to do!");
            System.out.println("For gather: \"+\"");
            System.out.println("For reduction: \"-\"");
            System.out.println("For division: \"/\"");
            System.out.println("For multiplication: \"*\"");
            System.out.print(":");

            String operation = ab.nextLine();


            try {
                System.out.print("Input first number: ");
                int nr1 = ab.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input second number: ");
                int nr2 = ab.nextInt();

                int gather, reduction, division, multiplication;
                gather = nr1 + nr2;
                reduction = nr1 - nr2;
                division = nr1 / nr2;
                multiplication = nr1 * nr2;
                switch (operation) {
                    case "+":
                        System.out.println("The result is: " + gather);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        System.out.println("The result is: " + reduction);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        System.out.println("The result is: " + division);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        System.out.println("The result is: " + multiplication);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println(" !!!! You haven't chosen an operation...  \n **** Input smth like: \n+ -> gather\n- -> reduction\n/ -> division\n* -> multiplication");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println(" ------------------------------ You have to choose an operation ------------------------------");
            }


            System.out.println("Do you keep going? Yes/ No");
            Scanner tx = new Scanner(System.in);
            answer = tx.nextLine();
        }

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    }
}
```

Fixed the code formatting u need shift `switch` inside try block as it needs to access variable declared inside it.